# Is it possible to connect to partitioned topic in Azure Service Bus with AMQP.Net Lite library?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, amqp, azure-servicebus-topics, amqp.netlite

My client .NET Core application uses [AMQP.Net Lite library](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite) to work with Azure Service Bus. When the topic in the service bus namespace is NOT partitioned (`Enable Partitioning` is turned *OFF*), everything works fine - I'm able to connect and create `ReceiverLink` object to receive messages.

However, as soon as the topic is partitioned (`Enable Partitioning` is turned **ON**), I get the following error immediately after `ReceiverLink` object creation.
The error description is: "*Cannot open a Topic client for entity type Subscriber.*"

The error code translates to the AMQP map as `amqp:not-allowed`. According to [the docs](https://azure.github.io/amqpnetlite/api/Amqp.ErrorCode.html#Amqp_ErrorCode_NotAllowed), it means "*The peer tried to use a frame in a manner that is inconsistent with the semantics defined in the specification.*" To be honest, I can hardly understand what it means in terms of Azure Service Bus abstractions, but it sounds depressing and similar to "*not possible*" to me...

On the other hand, [the MS docs state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-partitioning#latest-added-features) that AMQP can be used to send and receive messages:

> AMQP is now supported for sending and receiving messages to and from a **partitioned** entity.

So, the question is whether it is at all possible to use AMQP.NET Lite library to receive messages from a partitioned topic in Azure Service Bus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it turns out to be a bug in Azure Service Bus. There's a workaround, however.

Instead of creating the `ReceiverLink` like this:

```
var r = new ReceiverLink(session, "SubscriptionName", "TopicName");
```

Create it like this:

```
var r = new ReceiverLink(session, string.Empty, "TopicName/Subscriptions/SubscriptionName");
```

NOTE: the second parameter can be any string.

See [this Github thread](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite/issues/427) for details.

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand, [the MS docs state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-partitioning#latest-added-features) that AMQP can be used to send and receive messages:

> AMQP is now supported for sending and receiving messages to and from a
> partitioned entity

This article from Microsoft docs is published in 23rdJun, 2020:
[image]

But last update on [AMQP.Net Lite library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AMQPNetLite.Core/2.4.0) is 5 Months ago, so it's unlikely that support is present right now and is yet to be added to open source library:

[image]

You can either raise a pull request or issue for the support in [Github repo](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite)

Comment: Your assumption might very well be the case, thanks! I did raise the issue on Github as well: https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite/issues/427